# Functional analysis - check that a closed subspace of a Hilbert space is convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that V is a Hilbert space over $F$ and $W$ is a closed subspace of $V$ . Then for every $x \in V$ , there exist unique $y \in W$ and $z \in$ (the orthogonal compliment of $W$) such that $x = y + z$.

The proof was based on the fact that $W$ is convex in $V$, and which I couldn't get since we have no clue about the structure of the subspace $W$.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of the words "convex" and "subspace"?

Comment: Yes, since a subspace must contain all linear combinations it contains all convex combinations

Comment: I need more details please..I'm not sure I fully understand what you're saying...

Answer (score 3):

To say $W$ is a subspace of $V$ means that for vectors $x,y \in W$ and "scalars" $\alpha , \beta \in F$  You have $\alpha x + \beta y \in W$, so as well if $\theta \in [0,1]$ (Your field $F$ should contain this interval) You have $\theta x + (1-\theta)y$, i.e. every point of the line segment between $x$ and $y$ is in $W$. This last property is exactly the convexness of $W$, that You need (together with its closedness) to prove there is an orthogonal projection on $W$.

Comment: thank you very much sir this was very helpful ^_^...